# How do I equally scale elements regardless of their width/height

Tags: css, sass, scale

I am looking for a way to scale my elements equally based on any number/px regardless of their width and height. So not proportional to their size.

[**JSFiddle version**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirExotic/wauLkbxp/23/)

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #20262E;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 25px;
  transition: transform 1s;
}
.box:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}


.one {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.two {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orangered;
}

.three {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="box one"></div>
<div class="box two"></div>
<div class="box three"></div>
```

I know I could apply the scale effect to each individual element and manually decide how much they should scale vertically and horizontally, which would look like the **example below**, but I want it in one line so it can always be changed from the source.

[**JSFiddle version**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirExotic/wauLkbxp/25/)

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #20262E;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 25px;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.one {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
.one:hover {
  /* Add 5px to height and width (1.1 scale = 2.5px added on each side) */
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.two {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orangered;
}
.two:hover {
  /* Add the same 5px to height and width by applying half of the same scale (1.05) */
  /* because the width and height are double that of box one. */
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.three {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: tomato;
}
.three:hover {
  /* Here we apply the same 1.05 scale to the height, but apply another scale */
  /* for the width because it is 3 times bigger, but still want to add only 5px. */
  transform: scaleY(1.05) scaleX(1.016666667);
}
```

```html
<div class="box one"></div>
<div class="box two"></div>
<div class="box three"></div>
```

As you can see in the Fiddle, the values in `scale()` are different depending on the height and width, and if they height and width are different from each other, you need a `scaleX()` and `scaleY()` and this is just not manageable on a bigger scale (pun not intended, but I wish it was - it's a good one!)

Now I thought of something like `scale(calc(1 + 5px)` so the height and width stay the same `scale(1)` but with the addition of `5px`, but unfortunately it's not that simple.

If there is a Sass solution, I am happy to accept that too!

> **Note:** this effect should be able to be applied to any element, so it
>   is not just about the height and width of the background. Imagine the
>   boxes to be styled buttons where every part of that button has to be
>   scaled.

Comment: Now I thought of something like `scale(calc(1 + 5px)` so the height and width stay the same `scale(1)` but with the addition of `5px`, but unfortunately **it's not that simple**.
But... why it isn't?

Comment: If it's only about the background you can add padding on the hover, so all the boxes will increase with the same amount. However the content will not scale.

Comment: @AndrzejZiółek try and see, scale doesn't accept such values, you cannot use pixel, you need to provide the scale ratio so there is no unit because scale will do a multiplication of unit

Comment: Duh, sure. My fault, didn't think about it. Your solution with negative margin is awesome @TemaniAfif, upvoting.

Answer (score 2):

If `scale` is not mandatory I would consider another trick to make the element bigger using width/height and negative margin. You will then need to write the CSS only one and it will apply to all:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #20262E;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 25px;
}

.one {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.two {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orangered;
}

.three {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.box > div  {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:inherit;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.box:hover > div  {
  margin:-5px;
  width:calc(100% + 10px);
  height:calc(100% + 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box one">
<div ></div>
</div>
<div class="box two">
<div ></div>
</div>
<div class="box three">
<div ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but sadly this would only work for backgrounds and/or heights and widths. I need to apply my `scale()` to `a` tags styled as buttons, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: @SirExotic in this case what will mean the +5px? it won't have any meaning for intern elements

Comment: The 5px was just an example of the way I wanted it to work. It doesn't have to be literally 5px.

Comment: @SirExotic yes but what is this value? what's it's meaning with text for example ... we can find it logical with height/width but I don't see what is a scale `1 + Xpx` for any element

Comment: Like I said, it doesn't have to be `5px`, it could be something else than px, or just another method. And if I knew what that was, I wouldn't be asking the question :p

Comment: @SirExotic well, if you don't know what it can be then we cannot help :) ... for me if you apply `scale(1.5)` it's already an equal scale between all the elements but it's seems not for you, so we need an accurate definition about what is an *equal* scale for you, based on what? when we can say we have equality? what is the unit? etc

Comment: I thought I had explained it well enough in my question, but maybe this will help. The `.5` in `scale(1.5)` means 50% of 1 (the *whole*), so if the width is 100px, then it is 50% of 100px = 50px. But if the width is 300px, then 50% is 150px. I don't want to scale the elements by % based on the element's width that is hovered, but I want to apply one style/value to all elements. See my second Fiddle for the visualization.